# Pay voters for voting, or not, in NH

Tags: united-states, voting, new-hampshire

I'm aware of a relevant [law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/597) discussed in a related [thread](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48655/are-us-laws-against-vote-buying-unenforceable/48656#48656), but the law is not clear to me still.

It's not clear to me by the language of the law whether "consideration of his vote or the withholding of his vote" regards voting *per se*, or voting a particular way/for a particular candidate. Is this open to interpretation as to this question? For instance, could a restaurant owner offer discounted prices only to people who voted, regardless of the candidates and proposals voted for? Could a person in NH pay someone to vote or not vote regardless of the details of the vote?

This *seems* to be legal to my untrained eyes because government employees commonly give small in-kind payments to people who vote, for instance pens, masks, and stickers, but perhaps that would be a crime if instead the amount of money equal to a pen, mask, and a sticker were given.

Comment: If you went into a polling place and politely asked for a pen, but were not in the process of voting do you think they might give it to you? It may not be a quid-pro-quo but a gift to anyone who asks.

Comment: In general there is a concept of *de minimis* where the precise value is not zero but it is legally treated as if it is. A sticker bought in bulk rolls costs literally less than a penny and is worth literally nothing. A reusable cloth mask (a couple dollars?) might be pushing it but if it is a promotional item and anyone can have one as George White suggested it might be ok.